# Pass function pointer to nested class

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have a nested class `B` inside class `A`. I need to pass a custom function with one integer argument and return type of void at runtime to class B.

This is how I tried to do it. First I passed the function through the constructor of A. And then to pass it to B, I tried to use pointer to member function. However I can't figure out how to call function `foo()` inside `doStuff()`.

```
class A {
    void(*f)(int);
    A(void(*f)(int)) : f(f) {};
    class B {
       void(*A::*foo)(int) = &A::f;
       void doStuff() {
          var = 10;
          *foo(var); //Doesn't work
       } 
    };
};

void testFunction(int a) {
     //do something
}

A a(testFunction);
```

What is the correct way to call it? And does this solution make sense as the whole?

Edit: Possible alternative solution:

```
class A {
  A(void(*f)(int)) {
     b = B(f);
  }
  class B {
    void(*f)(int);
    B() {}
    B(void(*f)(int)) : f(f) {}
    
    void doStuff() {
        var = 10;
        f(10);
    }
   };
   B b;
};
```

Comment: Why not just pass the function pointer to B's ctor?

Comment: Handy reading: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members But also read about `std::function`.

Comment: @StephenNewell Do I have to create object of B for that? I would like to solely initiate object of A like this `A a(testFunction)` and have function passed to B, without having to create object of B.

Comment: @LennyWhite `Do I have to create object of B for that?` The way you have it now, you *must* create an object of type `B` some way or another, because `doStuff` is a member function of `B` and you need an instance of `B` to call it. Note that creating an object `A a;` does *not* create any instance of a `B` object. `class B` is "*nested*" in `A`, but that's just the declaration. `class A` has no member of type `B`.

Comment: @dxiv What if I have a member of `B` inside class `A`?

Comment: @LennyWhite Technically you could do that, and you could also arrange for the embedded `B` object to store a reference to its "owner" `A` object. But what's the point i.e. why would you prefer to then call `a.b.doStuff(10);` instead of `a.f(10);`?

Comment: @dxiv I made an edit. Maybe I could do it like that?

Comment: @LennyWhite - Your latest edit seems fine.  Did it work for you?

Comment: @LennyWhite That would work, though the `A` constructor would normally be written as `A(void (*f)(int)) : b(f) { }` instead.

Comment: @dxiv Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that in order to call a pointer-to-function member of `A` you need an object of type `A` to call it on. In the example below, the reference to an `A` object was passed as an argument to `B::doStuff`.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    void (*f)(int);
    A(void (*f)(int)) : f(f) { }

    class B {
    public:
       void (*A::*foo)(int) = &A::f;

       void doStuff(A &a) {
          (a.*foo)(10);
       } 
    };
};

void testFunction(int a) {
      std::cout << "inside testFunction(" << a << ")" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  A a(testFunction);

  A::B b;
  b.doStuff(a);
}
```

[Example output](https://godbolt.org/z/7aMEfr):  `inside testFunction(10)`.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can't use this approach with passing object A to `doStuff()`. Having to create object B, and then passing A as argument, would be a bit too messy for my situation.

Comment: @LennyWhite You don't have to pass the object reference to `doStuff` as an argument, you just have to make it available somehow. You want to call the function via the pointer stored in `A`, so you need an instance of `A` for that. Otherwise there is no point to make `A::f` a member of `A` to begin with.

Comment: I undestand. In that case I guess I need to look for another solution to what I implemented, where I could pass the function directly to B. Instead of through accessing member of A.

Comment: @LennyWhite You know how to do that, since that's how `A` works (so that for example you could call `a.f(10);` from `main` instead). Whether that's how you should/want to do it, however, is hard to tell without a lot more context.